# One-Many and One-One relationship using LINQ to SQL on Stored procedure

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Lets say I had Three tables Customer(ID,Name),CustomerAddress(ID,Address1,Address2),Phone(ID,PhoneNumber). So in this,Each Customer has Multiple Addresses(one-Many relation ship) and Each Address has one Phone (one-one relation ship). I had a stored procedure which returns all the data in below order

```
ID    Name   Address  PhoneNumber 
1001  John   MD       1234
1001  John   VA       1231
1001  John   WA       1232
1002  Mary   NJ       0231
1002  Mary   NY       0232
1002  Mary   OR       0032
```

Right now, after getting above data i am sitting in  a for each loop and filling my data objects.But, I want fill those Data objects dynamically using LINQ-SQL. I saw this article which exactly does the same thing http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/OneManyandOneOneLINQ.aspx?fid=1543095&select=3878390&fr=1&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick.
The only difference is i am running stored procedure to get data.
So, Any one knows hoe to fill these entity classes w/ stored procedure?
Any input would be really help full.

Comment: Why are you using stored procs?

Comment: Becoz, the requirement is like that. We need to use existing stored procedures. And above that, the above table is just a scenario.I need to get data from Multiple tables. So my existing stored procedure is already doing that.(Using lot of Joins). So its good for me to use the working/Tested stored procedure. Any inputs on this?